# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mobile

how can I solve this problem?
when I send POST request to the server...

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/data-search. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

//myservice.js

```
function setNewSearch(titleParam, ratingParam) {

            var data = {
                title: titleParam,
                rating: ratingParam
            };

            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/data-search', data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

            function successCallback(e){
                console.log('successCallback ' + JSON.stringify(e));
            }
            function errorCallback(e){
               console.log('errorCallback ' +JSON.stringify(e));
            }

        }
```

//my controller.js

```
$scope.newSearch = function(){
            NewSearchService.setNewSearch('john', 'white');
        };
```

---

//my server is :

```
app.post('/data-search', insertDataSearch);
function insertDataSearch(req, res) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    var newDataSearch = new dataSearch();
    newDataSearch.title = req.param('title');
    newDataSearch.rating = req.param('rating');

    newDataSearch.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in Saving newDataSearch: ' + err);
            throw err;
        }
        res.send("Sucess");
    });
}
```

this problem only occurs when I enter on $http.post the parameter 'data'

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem could be that data is a JavaScript object and not valid JSON

try this in the setNewSearch() function

```
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/data-search', JSON.stringify(data)).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your handler is throwing an error or some other issue processing the data is preventing it from replying with the allow origin headers?